# mysql temporary table privileges

Tags: mysql, select, mariadb, privileges, temp-tables

I am using mariadb as my application backend.

i need to create a temporary table (which is temporary per connection, so when the connection is lost it will gone; that is what i want), but i need store a value which should be constant so the user only read it (no update, delete or ... only select), and this value is different in every connection.

so my question is can i grant only **select privilege** on a specific **temporary table** in **mysql** or mariadb?

Comment: `CREATE TEMPORARY` creates a table that is _visible_ to that _connection_ only.  Do you need it visible to _other_ connections by that _same_ user?  (Then you need a different approach.)

Comment: actually i need to create store a value, which should be constant, i mean when i initialize it with a value, it should not be updated.
also it has to be at connection level, i need to store different value for different connections. and the value should be cleaned after connection dies.
variables are per connection but updateable.
temporary tables are also per connection but also updateable.

Comment: You want "write-once"?  There are no permissions allowing that.  And an `@variable` would be simpler than a temp table.

Comment: @RickJames yes, "write-once".

Answer (score 0):

according to the **MySQL 5.1 Documenation** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-temporary-tables, it can't be done.

in the documentation it is suggested to use another database dedicated to temporary tables, with specified privilege for it.